# checking files exist on a network share

Tags: powershell

My first post, totally new to this but i need help with the following:
i need a script that will check a network share for certain file names, and output that result to a txt file or csv file.
something like:
for each item listed in name.txt
check this network directory
and output the results back to a csv file
just not sure where to start, ive tried a few things but nothing works the way i expect it to

appreciate any help you can offer.

```
$computers = Get-Content "C:\...\textfile.txt"
$computers | ForEach-Object{
    Get-Childitem "C:\test\*" -Include "*" -Recurse | Select-Object Name, DirectoryName, Directory, Exists, FullName, CreationTime, LastWriteTime | Export-Csv -Path c:\output\list.csv -NoTypeInformation
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So assuming you have a text file called name.txt that has the file names and paths that you're looking for, something like should do the trick.

```
$namesFile = "c:\scripts\names.txt"
$allNames = Get-Content $namesFile
ForEach ($name in $allNames)
{
   if (Test-Path -path $name -PathType Leaf -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue )
   {
      Get-ItemProperty $name | select Name, DirectoryName, FullName, CreationTime, LastWriteTime | Export-Csv -Path c:\scripts\list.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append -Force
   }
}
```

Which will return list.csv containing the details of all the required files that do exist, and obviously doesn't include those that don't since they have no properties to return.

Comment: Thanks Keith
i'll try that now, much appreciated